# The conditional in Conad Barski's lisp function is redundant?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This question is related to the Chapter 6 code of Conrad Barski's Book, `Land of Lisp`.

The code is the following

```
(defun tweak-text (lst caps lit)
  (when lst
    (let ((item (car lst))
          (rest (cdr lst)))
      (cond ((eq item #\space) (cons item (tweak-text rest caps lit)))
            ((member item '(#\! #\? #\.)) (cons item (tweak-text rest t lit)))
            ((eq item #\") (tweak-text rest caps (not lit)))
            (lit (cons item (tweak-text rest nil lit)))
            ((or caps lit) (cons (char-upcase item) (tweak-text rest nil lit)))
            (t (cons (char-downcase item) (tweak-text rest nil nil)))))))
```

Now look at the `(lit ..)` part and the stuff below it .. `((or caps nil) ..)`, so my question is the following

- if `lit` is ever true,  it will be will be evaluated in the former expression stated
- if it is not true,  the latter expression will always evaluate to `(or caps false)` => `(or caps false)` which is pretty much useless?

So shouldn't the latter expression simply be `(caps (cons (char ...))` ?

This book has been read by thousands so I must be wrong about something and I'm not John Bell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the simpler expression is equivalent. It is mentioned in the page 97 errata http://landoflisp.com/errata.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is the use of recursion, which limits the length of lists the function is able to process.

```
(defun tweak-text (list &aux (caps t) (lit nil))
  (mapcon (lambda (c)
            (case c
              (#\space (list c))
              ((#\! #\? #\.)
               (setf caps t)
               (list c))
              (#\"
               (setf lit (not lit))
               ())
              (otherwise
               (cond (lit (setf caps nil) (list c))
                     (caps (setf caps nil) (list (char-upcase c)))
                     (t (setf caps nil lit nil)
                        (list (char-downcase c)))))))
          list))
```

Comment: awesome to know, just wondering how does that relate to the question?

Comment: @nerorevenge: the actual question has been answered (see the answer by sigjuice). Keep in mind that the code has more 'problems' than what you have detected already.

Comment: understood.  Are there any more problems other than recursive nature of the mentioned main function?

Comment: @nerorevenge: in this example the 'problems' are not really errors or limitations, but more of stylistic nature. Some of that is because the book avoids more complicated Lisp constructs - it addresses beginners